# Xamarin System.Net.WebException missing WebExceptionStatus.NameResolutionFailure

Tags: exception, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have an exception I can't handle properly in `Xamarin.Forms` due to a missing member in the `WebExceptionStatus` enumeration, namely the `NameResolutionFailure` member.

[image]

Does anyone know how I can properly handle the exception in this specific case?

Comment: which environment is this in - Android, iOS, PCL, etc?  NameResolutionFailure should be == 1, you could try testing for that instead.

Comment: @jason iOS with PCL ... I'll add that and test later

Comment: It will only compile to a cast `case (System.Net.WebExceptionStatus)1:` wonder what that will do ....

Comment: @LamonteCristo did you ever resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

When looking at a [previous version of the `WebExceptionStatus` enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexceptionstatus(v=vs.100).aspx), the `NameResolutionFailure` member is not supported in a PCL.

What you can do to handle this issue is as follows:

```
case (System.Net.WebExceptionStatus)1:
    // your code
```

Or:

```
catch (System.Net.WebException ex)
{
    if ((int)ex.Status == 1)
        // your code
)
```

I tested this by simply throwing a new `WebException` like this:

```
throw new System.Net.WebException("Test", (System.Net.WebExceptionStatus)1);
```

Which, as I thought, returned an exception with `NameResolutionFailure` being the `StatusCode`.