# Unable to unlock iPhone or get past lock screen when app crashes (even after reboot)

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin.ios, crash, ios10

I wrote a test app using Xamarin and it crashed when in airplane mode [and the linked exception](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41413172/328397) wasn't caught.

Even after a reboot of the phone (power, down volume, home button) the phone was non responsive.

No other reboot sequence seem to work. (iPhone 7 with iOS 10)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that after a reboot the phone was stuck "processing the symbol files".

The way I resolved this was to remove the application using Xcode's Device Manager

[image]